# pytest - how to mock return a value from two different cursor calls in a method

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, magicmock

I have to write unit test in python. I need to mock two different cursor calls in a single method.

sql.py file

```
def call_sql(conn, b):
    
    query1 = q1
    query2 = q2

    cur = conn.cursor()
    run1 = cur.execute(query1).fetchone()
    run2 = cur.execute(query2).fetchone()

    count1 = run1[0]
    count2 = run2[0]

    if count1 == count2:
        print('success')
    else:
        print('fail')
```

---

```
def test_Call_sql(self):
    mock_connect = MagicMock()

    connection = mock_connect.return_value
    cursor = connection.cursor.return_value
    cursor.fetchone.return_value = (5,)
```

Question: how to mock two separate calls ?

Comment: is there any way to directly mock count1 and count2 ? so that I can verify both the conditions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several issues with the code. As [@Kun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3663240/kun) correctly points out, you should use `side_effect`. However, when mocking take note of the function calls and what returns and what doesn't. In your attempts you do not specify that the mock cursor needs to call `execute` as one of its calls, and have a return value for that as well. Below, is the code slightly modified which works as expected. I changed your function to return a boolean as that is easier to test than capturing printing to `stdout`.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
import pytest


def call_sql(conn):
    
    query1 = ""
    query2 = ""

    cur = conn.cursor()
    run1 = cur.execute(query1).fetchone()
    run2 = cur.execute(query2).fetchone()

    count1 = run1[0]
    count2 = run2[0]

    return count1 == count2


@pytest.mark.parametrize(
    "data,expected", 
    [
        ([(1, ), (1, )], True),
        ([(1, ), (2, )], False)
    ]
)
def test_Call_sql(data, expected):
    mock_connect = MagicMock()
    cursor = mock_connect.cursor.return_value
    cursor.execute.return_value.fetchone.side_effect = data

    assert call_sql(mock_connect) is expected
```

---

```
========================================= test session starts ==========================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.9, pytest-7.0.1, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: **
plugins: mock-3.7.0
collected 2 items                                                                                      

test_script.py ..                                                                                [100%]

===================================== 2 passed in 0.01s =====================================
```

Comment: thanks, it worked, I was missing a return_value on execute

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function to determine the output based on arguments on the side effect inside the MagicMock

```
def side_effect_func(val):
    if val == query1:
        # do sth
    if val == query2:
        # do sth

m = MagicMock(side_effect=side_effect_func)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [side effect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)

In your example, you will replace

```
cursor.fetchone.return_value = (5,0)
```

with

```
cursor.fetchone.side_effect = [(5,0), (6,0)]  # 1st call returns (5,0), 2nd call returns (6,0)
```

Comment: Tried this, but it still gives me some random mock id for both count1 and count2, it doesn't assign the value 5 or 6 as required

Comment: pls help in my issue